# reading parameters from create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recaptcha, spam-prevention

I have a ruby on rails project that is using the devise gem for authentication. I'm trying to use a captcha form in the sign up page to prevent bots from creating thousands of dummy logins

I'm not interested in using the recaptcha gem that works with devise as I haven't had any luck setting it up correctly.

I trying to set it up using this as a reference https://recaptchainrubyonrails.blogspot.com/

Here's my sign up page

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: 
registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
  <% end %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data 
sitekey="6LeeL5gUAAAAADbq0vt4d9biAs8oegkPx9ttUkKb"></div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>
<% end %>
<br>
```

I do have my routes file point to a separate registrations controller instead of the one created within the devise registrations

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' }, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

I can create a user regardless if I click on the captcha form. When I do click on it I get the parameter, g-recaptcha-response, in the create method that has a long text string such as

```
"g-recaptcha-response"=>"1234567890abcdefghi..."
```

I tried a create method that would look at that parameter and see if it is not nil. When it is nil I would like to back one page to the sign up page.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
      if not params[:g-recaptcha-response].present?
        redirect_to :back
      end
  end
end
```

I can't even get to the parameter as it errors out saying

```
undefined local variable or method `recaptcha' for #<RegistrationsController:0x7219e5a0> Did you mean? catch"
```

I'm trying to capture this parameter, look at the value of g-recaptcha-response and somehow cancel the creation of a user if the response was nil or empty string

Comment: Are this all the codes of  `RegistrationsController`? The error is saying that you are using a `recaptcha` method or variable somewhere inside your `RegistrationsController` that has not been defined anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried using `params[:"g-recaptacha-..."]` ? I'm not sure Ruby symbols can contain hyphens.

Comment: And instead of `not present?` you can use `empty?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `'g-recaptcha-response'` instead of `:g-recaptcha-response`. You need to use string syntax because you cannot use `-` in symbol naming

Comment: `:"g-recaptcha-response"` is a symbol, with dashes. It certainly is possible, just not as `:g-recaptcha-response`

Comment: and this is good code? I don't think so. In our company, we use string instead of symbols in this situation. It depends on code style in the company of course

Comment: Frederik's idea helped me actually get the string. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty, this is what I figured out that worked. Thanks to everyone who helped

```
    @response = params[:"g-recaptcha-response"]
    if @response == nil
        flash[:notice] = "Please click on captcha form!"
        redirect_back(fallback_location: new_user_registration_path)
    else
        flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully!"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
```